Struggling with git command
Here is the scenario:

Main Branch (Doesn't have the changes I need)
Development Branch (Changes I need are merged here)
Remote Feature Branch (This has the same changes which I need that are in the dev branch)

With that being said I'd like to copy the feature branch down to my local repository (it would be brand new on my local machine)
i've tried the following:
git pull <remote feature branch> <local feature branch>

but this did not work.
whenever i just try git clone i think its pulling from the main branch and not bringing down the changes i need

This question is similar to: What is a tracking branch?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you just want to checkout the feature branch locally and look at the code? or you want to add the changes from the feature branch to some other branch? if so, which one?

Hi, you can use the command git branch -a to check out the Feature branch locally, then run git checkout Feature and you have the changes in your local repository, to add them to your local branch run git checkout <my-branch-local> my-branch-local is your local branch, and then run git merge Feature

And when you address mb21's comment above, please [edit] and come up with a meaningful title that summarizes your problem. "Struggling with " could be the title to any question on this site. Thank you.

THank you Fredrich what used the how to merge a remote branch locally link

Add the remote repo:
git remote add origin <remote-repo-url>

Fetch all branches from remote:
git fetch origin

Create and switch to a new local branch that tracks the remote features branch:
git checkout -b <local-feature-branch> origin/<remote-feature-branch>

You can then verify of the branch is tracking the remote feature branch like this:
git branch -vv

You can also follow this method here: How to merge a remote branch locally

Assure that all remote branches are visible locally by using the command:
git fetch origin

Then to create a local branch that tracks the remote feature branch use the command:
git checkout -b <local-feature-branch> origin/<remote-feature-branch>

